# L200C regulated power supply - maximum current

Tags: voltage-regulator

Hi
I need to know what is the L200C maximum current. The datasheet says it's internally limited. Am not quite sure what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the data sheet (page 4) - peak short circuit current is 3.6 A, with pins 2 and 5 shorted. It'll probably go into thermal shutdown if you try it, unless it has a large heatsink.

Comment: ah OK! Why didn't they write it on same page grr· I ripped a heat sink out of an old AT power supply awhile back. Smart thinking!

Comment: The 3.6 A are available only when the voltage difference between input and output is 14 V, so that too needs to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

On the first page of the data sheet, it is said that it has adjustable current up to 2 A.

Another very important thing is note 1 on the page 4. It says that up to 2 A can be provided if the difference between input and output is less than 20 V (this came back and bit me couple of times).

Figure 3 on page 4 also provides interesting information. It shows relation between voltage difference, junction temperature and output current.